# Use str_replace to prevent php injection in uploaded HTML content

Tags: php, code-injection, str-replace

When client upload HTML content to server, I will check and remove PHP tags to prevent PHP injection. I read some posts, they almost said that I should use `preg_replace (regx)` or in better, I should parse html into `DOMDocument` object. However, I think that this methods will take time server do.

As I know, normal user (not malicious user) will never use php tag `(<?php, ...)` in html content. If they want display `<?php`, editor will convert `<` to `&lt;`. Therefore, for malicious user with html injection, I use `str_replace` to change all php tag to comment. For example:

```
$htmlStr = str_replace("?php", "<!--?php", htmlStr);
$htmlStr = str_replace("?>", "?-->", htmlStr);
```

It will not take time comparing with using `preg_replace` or `DOMDocument`. I know that the content can be affected (e.g. if tag `?>` is missing, all content are converted to comment). However, it is malicious user's content.

Is there any problem in this way? Do I think so simple?

Comment: I would rather look into what you are doing with user supplied content that you need to remove php tags. That code should never be executed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never build your own implementations of anti-injection scripts, unless you *really* know what you're doing.

If possible, prevent any user HTML based content. If not, use existing solution, such as [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/).